# Populate a Combobox with another Combobox dynamically

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013, combobox

I'm trying to populate a combobox with another combobox but something is wrong when changing values.

When i select an item in combobox1, it loads the values from the database as it should to combobox2, but when i then select another item in combobox1, combobox 2 show values from both my first and second item.

I need combobox2 to "forget" the first values and then show the next values once i change the item in combobox1.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Code below:

```
private void Cbx_ManageMedia_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ //Index change for combobox1

string query = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE type = '" + MIM + "'";
//MIM = Combobox1 value

MySqlConnection conDB = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand cmdDB = new MySqlCommand(query, conDB);
MySqlDataReader cReader;

try
{
    conDB.Open();
    cReader = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();

    while (cReader.Read())
    {
         string image = cReader.GetString("image");
         Cbx_ManageImagesImage.Items.Add(image);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
}
```

Comment: So when you change the first ComboBox Selected Index, all the items  in the second ComboBox change?

Comment: @Abhishek When i chose index in combobox1, combobox2 have the correct values, but if i change to another index of combobox1, combobox2 will display values from my first index and second index of combobox1, which is not what i want, i want it to only show values depending on what index i chose in combobox1

Comment: When you do a `Cbx_ManageImagesImage.Items.Add(image);`, the previous items will still be present in the ComboBox items. If you do a `ComboBox.Items.Clear()`, all items will be removed from it.

Comment: Looks like JRLambert answered your question

Comment: @Abhishek Yes he did, thanks for taking your time to answer though, highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to clear the existing items out of the combobox. If you change the first part of your code to read:

```
    private void Cbx_ManageMedia_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { //Index change for combobox1

    Cbx_ManageImagesImage.Items.Clear() //THIS LINE HAS BEEN ADDED
    string query = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE type = '" + MIM + "'";
    .......
```

all of the items will be cleared out of the combo box prior to adding in new items.